# Write a file on Heroku, or alternatives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an action that the user performs using a button on the app. I want to have a message on the page saying when the action was performed last (by any user). I need to save the date somewhere, but don't want a whole table for it, it's just one date. I have a file with just the date and when the user performs the action writes the current date to the file. Then the file is included in the view as part of the message. On Heroku writing to the file is failing. I don't know if it's because of the "read-only system" on Heroku, or because I've messed up the path to the file (but it works locally).

In the `application_controller`:

```
def lastreminded
   File.open("app/views/families/_lastreminded.html.erb", "w").puts(Date.today.strftime("%B %d, %Y").to_s + ".") 
end
```

I don't know if this is writing a new file in the wrong place, or not writing a file and I'm not sure how to inspect it on heroku, but I don't see anything about it in the logs.

I'm using Rails 3, but plan to upgrade soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku use a read-only filesystem, you may try to put the file in tmp directory, but it will be wiped. I'd recommend going with the db table.

On the other hand Rails models have an updated_at attribute you can use if your action ends updating any model.

Comment: Do you have users? any model loaded on the action? There is also, model.touch that just update the updated_at field in the model.

Comment: Thanks, I will do model.touch just to set the new date. Thanks for the suggestion!